# Tufte-latex: Full-width table

Tags: tables, tabularx, tufte

I'm using Tufte LaTeX, but I want to add a rather big table to my document (for detail see my example below). Due to the large tufte-margin this is becoming a bit of a hassle.

I know it's easily possible to extend a figure beyond the usual textwidth into the margin, is it possible to do the same with a table?

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\title{}

\author[]{}

%\date{28 March 2010} % without \date command, current date is supplied

%\geometry{showframe} % display margins for debugging page layout
% deutsche Silbentrennung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage{graphicx} % allow embedded images
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
  \graphicspath{{graphics/}} % set of paths to search for images
\usepackage{amsmath}  % extended mathematics
\usepackage{booktabs} % book-quality tables
\usepackage{units}    % non-stacked fractions and better unit spacing
\usepackage{multicol} % multiple column layout facilities
\usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text
\usepackage{fancyvrb} % extended verbatim environments
  \fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}% default font size for fancy-verbatim environments

\usepackage{enumitem} % To customize itemize

\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlist{noitemsep} % No space between item

% Standardize command font styles and environments
\newcommand{\doccmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}% command name -- adds backslash automatically
\newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}% optional command argument
\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}% (required) command argument
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\textsf{#1}}% environment name
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% package name
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class name
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class option name
\newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quote}\noindent}{\end{quote}}% command specification environment

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|X|X|X} % \textwidth too small, alternative?
 One Word & Some Text & Some text & Some text \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the table in the `fullwidth` environment and use `\linewidth` for the width of the table:

```
\begin{fullwidth}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|X|X|X}% use \linewidth
    One Word & Some Text & Some text & Some text \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{fullwidth}
```

The `fullwidth` environment stretches across the main text block and the margin note area. Note that you should avoid allowing the contents of a `fullwidth` environment to stretch across multiple pages in `symmetric` mode (where the margin note area alternates between the left- and right-hand sides of the page).

The `\linewidth` length will correspond to the maximum width of the current line of text. If you use `\linewidth` and remove the `fullwidth` environment, `\linewidth` will be equal to `\textwidth`. If you were to move the table the margin area, `\linewidth` would be equal to `\marginparwidth`. I generally use `\linewidth` when I mean “take up all the available horizontal space.”

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I've tried `fullwidth` and I've tried `\linewidth`, but I've never tried them together. :)

Comment: How can I add a caption to this table?

Comment: @AK16 Instead of the `fullwidth` environment, you can use the `table*` environment and the usual `\caption` command. The `table*` environment is a full-width table, whereas the `table` environment is a text-width table.