# tufte-latex: Full-width algorithm2e blocks

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, tufte, fullwidth

I'm using `\documentclass{tufte-book}` and trying to get a full-width `algorithm` environment (specifically, using [`algorithm2e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)).

Minimum working example:

```latex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\title{Full-width algorithm2e algorithms}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only

\usepackage[lined, ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \tcp{Main loop}
    \While{not converged}{
        $a = a + 1$ \;
    }
    \caption{A text-width algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[2]

\marginnote[10pt]{This algorithm should be full-width, but isn't}
\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \tcp{Main loop}
    \While{not converged}{
        $a = a + 1$ \;
    }
    \caption{A full-width algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Which renders:

[image: Screenshot of rendered output from minimum working example]

In the `algorithm2e.sty` [source-code](https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty), I found the dimension `algowidth` defined about half way through the document.

```latex
%[snip]
\newdimen\algowidth%
%[snip]
```

So I've tried adjusting this length using `\setlength{\algowidth}{XXX}` in my example, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

- **How can I achieve full-width algorithm2e `algorithm` blocks with `tufte-latex`?**
- Bonus marks if `algorithm*` can be adjusted to be full-width by default.
- Extra bonus marks if the algorithm caption can also be moved to hang in the margin, as is the style with `tufte-latex` full width figures and tables.

---

Possibly related questions that don't seem to answer this:

- [Tufte-latex: Full-width table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333289/tufte-latex-full-width-table)
- [Adjust width of algorithm float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350434/adjust-width-of-algorithm-float)
- [Set width of algorithm environment (preferably document wide)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/set-width-of-algorithm-environment-preferably-document-wide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the most ideal solution since you loose the floating behaviour of the `algorithm`by enclosing it in a `minipage`, but you nevertheless already  deactivated the float mechanism by adding `[H]`...

[image]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\title{Full-width algorithm2e algorithms}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only

\usepackage[lined, ruled]{algorithm2e}

\newenvironment{widealgorithm}{\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]}{\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{fullwidth}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \tcp{Main loop}
    \While{not converged}{
        $a = a + 1$ \;
    }
    \caption{A text-width algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[2]


\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \tcp{Main loop}
    \While{not converged}{
        $a = a + 1$ \;
    }
    \caption{A full-width algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{widealgorithm}
    \tcp{Main loop}
    \While{not converged}{
        $a = a + 1$ \;
    }
    \caption{A full-width algorithm}
\end{widealgorithm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Works for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue also for floating algorithms (I had one that was also a whole page) you can define a new float and put the minipage into that float. This is a variation of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7493/87700). If I interpret this correctly, [this](https://mychemistry.eu/2017/04/define-new-floating-environment/) should require the `float` package, which tufte-latex loads for you.

```
% Reusing the preamble of leandriis' excellent answer
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\title{Floaty Full-width algorithm2e algorithms}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\usepackage[lined, ruled]{algorithm2e}

% Define a new float with name myalgo
% Default placement tbp and a file extension mya (for temp files)
% Cf. https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf
\newfloat{myalgo}{tbp}{mya}

% create a new environment called floatyalgorithm with one parameter (our algorithm code)
% Using this creates a new float through the myalgo float we defined above,
% which is filled with a minipage of full page width.
% The width is defined as the sum of a line, the margin and the sapce in between (since the fullwidth environment cannot help us here).
% For the variables names cf. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/page_size_and_margins
% As in leandriis' answer, use [H] for the algorithm to fill the space.
\newenvironment{floatyalgorithm}[1][tbp]%
{\begin{myalgo}[#1]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]}%
{\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{myalgo}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{floatyalgorithm}[tbp]
  $m := m'$;
  \caption{\lipsum[2]}
\end{floatyalgorithm}    

\end{document}
```

I have not extensively tested this. For my use case it worked nicely, but there might be some unwanted interactions with full pages and the content of the margin.